# Why is my Windows Forms App freezing when a button is pressed to bring up a new form?

Tags: c#, winforms, button

When a button (Make A Booking) is pressed to display the next window (MakeBooking) the application freezes and has to be manually stopped. Below is two code snippets for my first and second (to be displayed) form. It worked once but after that began freezing and not responding till program is exited. The button is declared in InitializeComponents

```
Initial Page Code

public partial class UI_Menu : Form
{
    public UI_Menu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void UI_Menu_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }



    private void btnQuit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }

    private void btn_Make_Booking_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var makebooking = new MakeBooking();
        makebooking.Location = this.Location;
        makebooking.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        makebooking.FormClosing += delegate { this.Show(); };
        makebooking.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Second Form to be displayed

```
    public partial class MakeBooking : Form
    {
        public MakeBooking()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void MakeBooking_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            //date of birth
            this.cmb_DD.Leave += new EventHandler(cmb_YYYY_Leave);
            this.cmb_MM.Leave += new EventHandler(cmb_YYYY_Leave);
            this.cmb_YYYY.Leave += new EventHandler(cmb_YYYY_Leave);

            //Adds Days, Months and Years to Combo Box
            for (int i = 0; i <= 31; i++)
            {
                cmb_DD.Items.Add(i.ToString());
            }

            cmb_MM.Items.Add("January");
            cmb_MM.Items.Add("Febuary");
            cmb_MM.Items.Add("March");
            cmb_MM.Items.Add("April");
            cmb_MM.Items.Add("May");
            cmb_MM.Items.Add("June");
            cmb_MM.Items.Add("July");
            cmb_MM.Items.Add("August");
            cmb_MM.Items.Add("September");
            cmb_MM.Items.Add("October");
            cmb_MM.Items.Add("November");
            cmb_MM.Items.Add("December");

            for (int y = 1900; y <= DateTime.Now.Year;)
            {
                cmb_YYYY.Items.Add(y.ToString());
            }
            //

        }

        


        private void cmb_YYYY_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int day = DateTime.DaysInMonth(Convert.ToInt32(cmb_YYYY.Text),
            cmb_MM.SelectedIndex + 1);
            if (day <= cmb_DD.SelectedIndex)
            {
                //alert message or your managing code.
            }

        }

        private void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create string variables that contain the patterns   
            string emailPattern = @"^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$"; // Email address pattern  
            string PostCodePattern = @"^((GIR &0AA)|((([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y]?[0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-PR-UWYZ][0-9][A-HJKSTUW])|([A-PR-UWYZ][A-HK-Y][0-9][ABEHMNPRV-Y]))) &[0-9][ABD-HJLNP-UW-Z]{2}))$";
            string phonePattern = @"^(((\+44\s?\d{4}|\(?0\d{4}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3})|((\+44\s?\d{3}|\(?0\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{4})|((\+44\s?\d{2}|\(?0\d{2}\)?)\s?\d{4}\s?\d{4}))(\s?\#(\d{4}|\d{3}))?$="; // UK Phone number pattern   

            // Create a bool variable and use the Regex.IsMatch static method which returns true if a specific value matches a specific pattern  
            bool isEmailValid = Regex.IsMatch(txt_Email.Text, emailPattern);
            bool isPostValid = Regex.IsMatch(txt_Postcode.Text, PostCodePattern);
            bool isPhoneValid = Regex.IsMatch(txt_Phone_Num.Text, phonePattern);

            // Now you can check the result   
            if (!isEmailValid)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email");
            }

            if (!isPostValid)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid zip code");
            }

            if (!isPhoneValid)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid phone number");
            }

            else
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-1CO403C\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CS_Project;Integrated Security=True");
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer (First_Name, Last_Name, Phone_Number, Email, Address_Line_1, Town, Postcode) VALUES ('"+txt_F_Name.Text+"','"+txt_L_Name.Text+"', '"+txt_Phone_Num.Text+"', '"+txt_Email.Text+"', '"+txt_Addy_1.Text+"','"+txt_Addy_2+ "', '"+txt_Postcode.Text+"');", conn); 

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                cmd.Clone();
                conn.Close();


                MakeBooking2 BookingForm2 = new MakeBooking2();
                this.Hide();
                BookingForm2.ShowDialog();
            }
        }

        
    }
}
```

[Button Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKpsW.png)

I have tried deleting and recoding the button but same effect and consulting other forums but no luck.

Comment: I have tested your code. It is working fine. Please post more Information about the content of MakeBooking-Form.

Comment: You are hiding the form :  this.Hide();  Do you want to hide the makebooking form?

Comment: It looks like your `for` loop where you are adding years, within the form load function, is missing an increment at the end, `for (int y = 1900; y <= DateTime.Now.Year;)`. As it's written, the loop declares `y` as 1900, evaluates whether that's less than the current year, executes your code, but does no increment. So it will constantly evaluate whether 1900 is less than the current year. Another consequence is this is constantly adding 1900 into `cmb_YYYY.Items`. If that's not a hashset, that is just going to blow up in size.

Comment: Might be here for (int y = 1900; y <= DateTime.Now.Year; y++// add this)

Comment: You should debug your code and see what is happening in MakeBooking_Load. Then fix it.

Comment: The following may be of interest: [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2022)

Comment: **[Using the free, built-in Step Debugger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y740d9d3.aspx)** to debug your code is easier than you think.  It will also help you learn how code executes which in turn will help you write better code.

Comment: It was the for loop, thanks guys :)